# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive reals. show that lim $(1+a_1)...(1+a_n)$ exists and is nonzero iff series $a_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

When $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence if posiive real numbers, define $P_n = (1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_n)$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n$ exists and is a nonzero number iff $\sum a_n$ converges.

I am not sure how this would be so. Certainly each $(1+a_n)$ is greater than $1$ so it would seem that $P_n$ diverges.

Comment: Hint: $(1+a_1) \cdots (1+ a_n) \geq 1 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n$. On the other hand, use $\ln (1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}2 + \cdots \leq  x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_\infty P_n >0$ means the series $$\sum \ln (1+a_n) $$ is convergent and
$$\lim_\infty \ln(1+a_n)=0$$

thus $\lim_\infty a_n=0$.

the series $\sum a_n $ will be convergent since $\ln (1+a_n)\sim a_n $.

Comment: The last statement can be formally justified using the limit comparison test

Comment: @Joel Yes since $a_n>0$.